# problema al modificar variable global

Tags: javascript, variables, variables-globales

en esta ocasión vengo por un error bastante simple que me ocurrió, pero que me ha dejado pensativo.
Sucede que tengo una variable normal declarada de forma global, obviamente fuera de la función, y la misma al darle cick a un elemento de mi menú, debe aumentar en 1 su valor. esto la verdad ya lo había hecho antes y la verdad no suponía un problema, pero al repetirlo con esta variable, simplemente no quiere funcionar

*html*

```
 <div class=buscador>
     <input type="text" value="nombre" id="texto1" class=texto1>
      <input type="button" value="buscar" onclick="buscar()" class= "boton1">
  </div>
```

*javascript*

```
i2=0;
function buscar(){
    //buscador de texto
    //let texto=document.getElementById("texto1").value;
    // Obtener solo elementos en contenedor original
    //let texto2=b.getElementsByClassName(texto);

    //b.style.display="none";
    //bb.style.display="block";
    // Limpia el contenedor, no hay problema
    //bb.innerHTML="";

 i2=i2+1; //ya intenté con i2++, i2=+1;
 
    // Limitas el for con la cantidad de elementos obtenidos
    //for(let num=0; num<texto2.length; num++){
        // Inserta una copia, en lugar del original
        //bb.appendChild(texto2[num].cloneNode(true));
    }
 
}

if(i2<0){

  c.style.display="none"; //i2 se queda en 0 y sigue ejecutando esta parte
}
```

Ahora, apliqué eso mismo con el siguiente código y funciona:

*html*

```
<div value="a" class="a2" id="a2"><input type="button" value="Menu" onclick="menu2()" class= "menu2">
</div>
```

*javascript*

```
i=0;
function menu2 (){
 //infoc.style.display="none";
  //c.style.display="inherit";
   //a2.style.display="none"; 

 i=i+1;
}

 if(i==1){
    //a2.style.display="none";
     //b.setAttribute("style","margin-top:10px;"); //este si funciona
  }
```

la verdad es algo muy básico pero es que no encuentro diferencia alguna entre ambos códigos; he modificado variables de esta forma antes y ya intentado devolviendo su valor, cambiando el nombre, los símbolos  de (<>) por (==, =) y nada. Cabe destacar, todo lo demás, funciones... funciona perfectamente
Muchas gracias por todo

Comment: Puedes decirme como haces para que el condicional se valide en el tiempo de ejecución, si se encuentra fuera de tu función. Ya que dices que el ejemplo del if(i==1) {sentencia...} te funciona. Se supone que se ejecuta el if al cargar inicialmente el código js, pero después, cuando ejecutas tus metodos, no veo que realices en ellos el condicional.

Comment: Creo no haber comprendido del todo su pregunta, lo que yo busco con ese código son dos procesos independientes, se empieza ejecutando una función a través de un botón, el cual no coloco por no ser de relevancia. luego la variable grupal es utilizada dentro de esta función y aumenta en uno, y finaliza completando el código cuando el condicional compara su estado en mayor o menor que uno. Por supuesto, no está todo el código para no entorpecer. Espero sirva de algo mi respuesta

Comment: debes utilizar `let` o `var`, let lo puedes usar de la forma `let i = 0; fun(){ i=i+1}` o `var i = 0; fun(){ i=i+1}`, la diferencia entre una y otra es que let solo existe en ese ámbito global pero si la declaras de manera local no guardaría su valor y var permite reemplazar por referencia el valor, es decir desde cualquier parte puede ser modificado.

Comment: La pregunta está incompleta, es comprensible que no quieras poner todo el código, pero sí deberías incluir la parte donde ejecutas la función y donde analizas el valor de la variable. El problema puede ser de contexto o alcance (scope) o del momento en que se ejecuta (lógica). Trata de crear un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que podamos probar para tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: Sería bueno que coloques solo el como llamas la función, la funcion ya la observo, pero el if no lo veo que esté siendo llamado en ninguna función. dado que ese if(i2<0){sentencia...} lo veo al mismo nivel que tu función. Si así está en tu código, está mal. Debería estar en la función que se está ejecutando. en este caso sería la función buscar()

Comment: en respuesta a jorge: ya eso lo he intentado, con ambas, y sigue sin funcionar. gracias de todas formas la alterntiva

Comment: en respuesta a triby: Bueno podría modificar mi comentario para aclarar más, pero la razón por la cual digo que no es relevante es que las funciones se están ejecutando perfctamente con los demás elementos, se activa cuando debe, etc, pensé que sería más molesto colocar mucho código simple. ya modifico mi duda, gracias

Comment: en respuesta a jorge gomez: Es que no quiero que se encuentre dentro del buscar, debido a que los parámetros que están dentro de este if, deben ejecutarse todo el tiempo, menos cuando active  la función buscar, es la forma más básica de comparar el estado de esa función, o al menos eso intentaba. Gracias por la atención